# Finding adjoint of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose I have a process

$$\eta = \frac{2-\tau}{\tau}$$

which is a Markov process taking values in $[1,\infty)$, which has infinitesimal generator

$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{a}\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}(\eta^2-1)\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}$$

where $a$ is a constant. How do I show $\mathcal{L}$ is self-adjoint, ie

$$\int \phi(\eta)\mathcal{L}\psi(\eta) d\eta = \int \phi(\eta)\mathcal{L}^{\star}\psi(\eta) d\eta$$

where $\mathcal{L^{\star}}$ is the adjoint of $\mathcal{L}.$

Comment: You need to integrate by parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** You need to show that 
$$\int \phi\mathcal{L}\psi dx = \int \phi\mathcal{L}^{\star}\psi dx$$

By definition
$$\int \phi\mathcal{L}^{\star}\psi dx= \int \psi\mathcal{L}\phi dx$$

Therefore, to show that $\mathcal L$ is selfadjoint you need to show that 
$$\int \phi\mathcal{L}\psi d\eta =\int \psi\mathcal{L}\phi d\eta$$

Comment: Are $\psi,\phi$ test functions? I am confused as to how to treat them...

Comment: Your operator is defined as an operator on functions, $\phi, \psi$ are such functions. Proving the relation should be standard integration by parts.

Comment: @rodger_kicks Look at the definition of an "infinitesimal generator" for a MArkov process to see exactly what your test functios are. Also, your integral is probably from $1$ to $\infty$, again check the definition.

Comment: My test functions should be $\phi(\eta),\psi(\eta)$ and the integral should be $d\eta$. Does that make sense? I'm still struggling to find the adjoint...

Comment: @rodger_kicks You don't need to find the adjoint... You already know it: it is $\mathcal L$. You just need to show that it satisfies the definition of the adjoint.

Comment: Thanks, I have managed to show this. Is the reason for the test functions being evaluated at the boundary being equal to zero, due to compact support? Thanks.